# Why is my file not printing what it's reading?

Tags: c++, file, filereader

```
void reportQnty(vector <Item> & items)
{
    int x = 0;
    bool MoreData = true;
    string line;
    fstream Report;
    Report.open("Report.txt");
    if(x == 0 && Report.is_open())
    {
        for (int i = 0; i< 11; i++)
        {
        Report << items[i].getName() << " ";
        Report << items[i].getonHand() << endl;

        }
    }
    while (MoreData == true)
    {
        if (Report.eof())
        {
            MoreData = false;
        }
        else
        {
            getline(Report, line);
            cout << line << endl;
        }
    }
    Report.close();

}
```

When attempting to COUT, the file refuses to reproduce on the console.  I don't understand how this could be unless there is just some silly error.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help should generally provide a [mre] of the problem, which includes a function `main` and all `#include` directives. This allows other people to easily test your program, by simply using copy&paste. Also, it shows how you are calling the function `reportQnty`.

Comment: It's clear you have a `using namespace std` somewhere in your code. You would be wise to get rid of it.

Comment: When `getline` fails (because of eof?) the code still outputs `line`, even if nothing was read. The standard way to test for successful input is `while (getline(Report, line)) do_something();`

Comment: @BoP  's comment is probably correct, but without knowing how what was printed differed from what you expected to be printed, there's no way to tell.

Comment: what is "x" there for? also use of eof is wrong and the vector should be passed as consr

Comment: A) does the file exist? You need to use `std::ios::in | std::ios::out | std::ios::trunc` instead of the default value `std::ios::in | std::ios::out` as mode to create a new file, if none exists. You definetly should deal with the case where the file is not opened successfully after calling `open`, since there are more possible reasons for the file to not be open after the `open` call (e.g. missing permissions or a directory of the same name already existing). B) check `Report.tellg()` before reading. Hint: the read position should be at the end of the file when trying to read.

Comment: ^^^ so `Report.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);` is needed to reset the read position to the start of the file.